# What does "We stand grateful" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, greetings

I am writing a thank-you letter to donors. I noticed that previous letters used "We stand grateful" as the ending. I was wondering if this expression is ok and if there is a better expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unusual - it sounds extremely formal, even a little old-fashioned.

You could just say "we *are* grateful".

If you want to say something more powerful, to express that your gratitude is enduring, there is a recognised phrase "we are *eternally* grateful", although this can seem a little excessive. You could perhaps say "we *remain* grateful".

You could also say "*you have our gratitude*", which implies that your gratitude is something tangible they can hold onto. Or, "*you have our lasting gratitude*".

Comment: "extremely formal, even a little old-fashioned." - "I stand grateful and amazed" ... Yale School of Drama Annual Magazine - 2013.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So you're saying that the language used by a **drama school** isn't extremely formal and old fashioned? These are people that still read Shakespeare...

Comment: I was echoing, not disputing, your remark. Especially about Yale.

Comment: There are dozens of written instances of [***We remain gratefully yours***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+remain+gratefully+yours%22) in Google Books, but only one of ***We stand grateful to you*** (and that's *not* the closing line of a letter). The cited variant is just that - an "unusual" variant.